# Can assignments be deferred and execution of current block continue?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, deferred-execution

I have been given some educational literature explaining asynchronous happenings in JS...

> Take the following example where, server1 is a different server to the one running the website and the getData() function will execute a complex SQL query and then **return a large dataset**:

```
var data = server1.getData();  
console.log(data);
```

> We can be almost certain that the console will say `undefined`. This is because the 2nd line of code will be executed before the result of getData() is returned.

My understanding is that the 2nd line will only be executed when then function has returned and its return value is assigned to `data`. If, indeed, getData() returns 'a large dataset', then by the time we get to the 2nd line `data` will be, 'a large dataset'.

Can assignment be deferred like this? I'm very familiar with async calls to remote servers and handling them through callbacks. But I believe that a simple function call in JS will return once (at most) and code is essentially executed single-threaded and sequentially executed.

Is this documentation somewhat misleading in its attempts to explain the pitfalls of asynchronous programming, however well intentioned?

Comment: No, assignments can't be deferred. I don't know what you're reading but that's a terrible example.

Comment: You can do deferred assignment with `async/await` ( https://ponyfoo.com/articles/understanding-javascript-async-await) but I don't see those keywords in your snippet.

Comment: Also noting that async/await are not standard js, i think it's part of ES7 Draft

Comment: @chiliNUT - `async/await are not standard js, i think it's part of ES7 Draft` - I think you'll find async/await is part of the ES2017 **specification** - which is a standard, not a draft :p also, ES2017 I think is more like ES8 ... ES6 = ES2015, ES7 = ES2016 and ES8 = ES2017 (people should stop using ES6/7/8 in preference to ESyyyy :p )

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks, I mixed up "latest draft" of the spec, according to mdn

Comment: Wow I'm just getting schooled in some terms today. Better online than in the office ;P

Comment: by the way @chiliNUT - the first link in `async` on MDN does point to draft, but that's the ES2018 draft :p - as far as "schooled", I hope you didn't take any offence, if ES6=2016, ES7=2017 etc it would be a little easier to remember which ES was which year :p but I always get it wrong which ES? == ESyyyy

Comment: @JaromandaX I meant it in a funny way since you nabbed me on not just 1 but 2 different things. It'd be pretty silly to be offended by the javascript guy with the awesome elven quagmire icon for politely correcting my programming terminology on a q/a site dedicated to programming.

Comment: @pointy ah it's always nice when I think the same thing as Pointy! :)

Comment: Lol well you know what I mean I hope - it's really problematic to include bad/broken code as examples, because it's almost never obvious what makes the code bad. A real example, perhaps with a callback or obvious Promise use, would have done the same job but with much more explanatory potential and without causing as much head-scratching.

Comment: Well this example is at the start of a section to introduce promises. The course, to be fair, isn't a "js" course but needs to cover off some js fundamentals in order to get to the real content. I just saw this bit of code and I thought "could that ever be right??" I raised it with Teach and he kind of defended it with some *much* more involved examples. I was still grumbling but let it go (cos I'm a grown man) :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation could be either misleading, or a deliberate attempt to pose a situation that won't work in order to explain why it won't work... which I would call misleading anyway.

JavaScript is single threaded - so any call out from the event queue must run to completion and return to the event queue (task manager) before another call out can begin.

```
 var data = server1.getData();  
 console.log(data);
```

**could** return a large set of data, if and only if obtaining the data was requested as a synchronous operation, and further provided that the server "server1" allows   [cross origin requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)  (presuming "different server" means a different domain, protocol or port).  Synchronous data requests are seriously discouraged as they stop the web page responding until the request is complete. If coded this way, the value of `data` would only be `undefined` it deliberately chosen as a value to indicate "no data available".

The `await` operator introduced in ECMAScript 2017 *can* wait on a promise of an asynchronous result to become fulfilled, and delay assignment of the result to a variable. But usage such as

```
var data = await server1.getData();
console.log(data);`
```

has restrictions that prevent its use in the example: it can only be used inside an `async` function, and `async` functions return a Promise object. So even if the `server1.getData` method were written as an `async` function, and internally used `await` to wait for data arrival, assign it to a variable and then return if from the function, the return value of an `async` function is **not returned** to its caller but used to fullfill the promise it returned when the call was actually made.

```
server1.getData().then( data=>console.log(data)).catch(err=>console.error(err));
```

is how the asynchronous operation might be coded to work if `getData` returns a promise. If called, call back functions provided by `.then` and `.catch` are called asynchronously, some time later. Meaning the code executing the above line can return to the event loop and let other things happen before the result of the query is sent back to the requesting web page.

As for

> > We can be almost certain that the console will say undefined.

using the provided code? No. More likely in code for current (ECMA script version 6 or later compliant) browsers, we can be almost certain the console will say `Promise { <state>: "pending" }` or similar.

Comment: Interesting stuff on await. I don't have a problem with a function that returns data or even a function that returns data slowly. But I do have a problem with the statement that the second line executes before the function call in the first line has returned. Even in the await example the function has returned a promise. In the example as shown getData() *must* have returned undefined (or lacked a return statement at all) by my understanding.

Comment: Perhaps "the 2nd line of code will be executed before the result of getData() is returned." is badly phrased and means "returned from the other server after running the query". As you say if `getData` initiates an asynchronous request and returns, the return value is going to be undefined and certainly not the data.  I suspect the material is setting up a discussion of the code idiocy that returns data from an asynchronous completion callback to the event loop (which ignores it), expecting the return value to jump back in time and end up as the return value of the .request to obtain the data.